# Is there anyway to change the tempo in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro, logic

I'm trying to script Logic Pro X only using keyboard commands. So far I can do everything I need to do except change the tempo. Is there anyway to change the tempo only using the keyboard?

Comment: You can add a key command to tap the tempo but I'm not sure about changing it to a specific tempo. Have you looked in the list of actions available with key commands?

Answer (score 2):

The only way it seems to be possible is by using 'Tempo Operations', which you can assign a keyboard shortcut to. Although it's possible, it's certainly not ideal. 
You would have to hit your chosen command to bring up 'Tempo Operations', then alter the start and end values for 'Position' and the start and end values for 'Tempo' by tabbing through the value boxes (For position, you could enter say '1000', which would apply the tempo to the end of your project unless it exceeded 1000 bars. Also, make sure the start and end tempos are the same).

Like I said, it's not just a simple tap of a command, but it looks like the only way to do it using only your keyboard.

Comment: So close, I just can't figure out a way to press the Apply button.

Comment: @FigBug Ah, I presumed you would just be able to tab to it, sorry.

Comment: It's weird, you can usually hit Apply with Return or Space, but most of the keyboard commands still control the main logic window. Not a standard dialog box. Oh well, thx for the idea.